# In wxpython, how to make frame fully transparent, while line is visible?

Tags: python, wxpython

```
import wx

class DrawPanel(wx.Frame):
  def __init__(self): 
    wx.Frame.__init__(self,None,title="Draw",size=(150,150)) 
    self.SetTransparent(0) 
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
  def OnPaint(self, event=None):
    dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
    dc.SetPen(wx.Pen(wx.BLACK, 5)) 
    # Draw a line 
    dc.DrawLine(0, 0, 150, 150)  

app = wx.App()
frame = DrawPanel()
frame.Show(True)
app.MainLoop()
```

Now frame and line are all invisible.

Please tell me how to make frame fully transparent, while line is visible ?

Answer (score 0):

When you make the frame transparent, it makes all its children transparent too. Thus, this really isn't possible. You can make semi-transparent drawings though via GraphicsContext. And you could take a look at GLCanvas (a wrapper for OpenGL) or you might be able to cobble something together with Cairo. See the wxPython demo package (available from [www.wxpython.org](http://www.wxpython.org)) for examples.